# APNs device token update when using multiple devices by the same user

Tags: ios, token

Seems like all the other info I found was out-of-date. 
Consider one user that has iPhone and iPad and the same app is installed on each device. When logging in for the first time from each device, the unique device token will be placed in the database to be used for future notifications. Below is the method I use to get device token in AppDelegate:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application   
 didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken(NSData*)deviceToken
    {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:deviceToken forKey:@"token"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
```

... so that later I can use it at the login process.

Now, if for some reason the app gets uninstalled and re-installed again, or after iOS update, the device token will be different and I have to update records in the database.

If I had to deal with just one device per user, then I would go by user id, deleting the previous record and inserting the new one. But in case of multiple devices ... how do I identify which database record to update, which token is not in use anymore?

Is there some unique Device ID that NEVER changes???

Answer (score 0):

Everytime the app is launched, the updated device token will come in the same method you are using to store the device token. So you can use a logic there only to save and update the token.

You have the current token stored in the UserDefaults, so just delete that token first from the database and then update the new token. 
You can do this in the same method in which you are saving the token. For that every time you have to check whether the current device token is in database? If yes, then delete it and update it for the user ID. If no, just save this one in the database for the user ID.

Comment: No. It doesn’t work that way if I uninstall and then reinstall the app. UserDefaults will be empty. But the older token is still in the database.

Comment: You can try deleting every tokens when the user is logged in first time, and other device's token should be updated every time the app is launched. Although there is a catch, for the short time in which the device tokens will be deleted and the device is still active then you won't be able to send the notifications in this short span of time.